# Checking if the end of the string is a whitespace character

Tags: android, textview, substring

I have a string which may or may not end with whitespace and I'm having trouble determining whether that's the case.

The reason why I am asking this is because I need a good way to calculate the width of the android since my string auto corrects and goes to the next line.

In android it looks like something like this:

```
 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy d - my method substrings the data to fit on screen.

|The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy  | - this is how it would look like on android

|dog---------------(empty space)----------|
```

Now to rephrase my question I want to know what method do I need to use to check the last character in my string is whitespace?

Comment: For what it's worth, a `String` always contains "characters", which may be whitespace, or not.  (Whitespace is still a "character".)  I edited your post to try to disambiguate this a bit, I hope I succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

<strike>boolean isSpace = yourString.charAt(yourString.length() - 1) == ' ';</strike>

**EDIT:**
After reading the great comment from MH bellow, you should instead use:

```
boolean isSpace = Character.isWhitespace(yourString.charAt(yourString.length() - 1));
```

But if you want only to remove the space at the end, you can use the `trim()` method on the `String` class:

```
yourString = yourString.trim();
```

Comment: thanks lol. My method of doing it was 10 times longer than yours checkString = s.substring(start,end);
            String tempString = checkString.substring(checkString.length() - 1,checkString.length());
            if(tempString != " ")
            {
             Boolean notYetTrue = false;
             while(notYetTrue){
              end = end - 1;
              tempString = checkString.substring(checkString.length() - 1,checkString.length());
              if(tempString == " "){
               notYetTrue = true;
              }
             }
            }

Comment: I would probably make the conditional check a bit more generic, since a 'space' is only one of many whitespace characters `[\t\n\x0B\f\r]`. Either compare against `\s` (character class for all whitespace characters), or use  [`Character.isWhitespace(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).